# How to mirror a CGPoint

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I wan't to rotate a touch point around the screen center 180 degrees (mirror it). I tried `ccpRotateByAngle(screenCenter, touchPoint, 180)`, but it gave me the wrong data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigonometry to the rescue:

```
// get your center in some way, here I'm using fixed coordinates 'cuz I'm lazy
CGPoint screenCenter = ccp(240, 160);

// this creates the vector between center and touch location
CGPoint touchPointToCenter = ccpSub(screenCenter, touchPoint);

// just add the vector to screen center and you mirrored it around center
CCPoint mirror = ccpAdd(screenCenter, touchPointToCenter);
```

For example, let's say your touch point is 200, 200:

```
touchPointToCenter: {240, 160} - {200, 200} = {40, -40}
mirror: {240, 160} + {40, -40} = {280, 120}
```

The mirrored point is 280, 120.

Note: the functions I used are from cocos2d-iphone. I assume they exist in cocos2d-x as well. They may be named differently, I'm not sure. You can also run the calculation "manually" like I did in the example.